# Set an entire layer's opacity instead of feature-wise without using multiple map divs?

Tags: openlayers

The issue here is that when you have a vector layer with polygons on top of each other and set layer opacity to something under 100%, their opacities seem to stack (which is a problem if you've used transparency to render an underlying layer visible). This also affects coloring.

So as the title says, do OpenLayers 3/4 have a native way of setting layer opacity post-feature-rendering? If not, is there a workaround for this that doesn't involve rendering multiple map divs on top of one another and passing events such as drag between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling I've come to realize that if separate `map` objects share the same `view`, any map movement is shared between them without the need to pass events manually:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <style>
        .map {
            height: 300px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class='map' id='map0'></div>

    <div class='map' id='map1'></div>

    <script>
        var shared_view = new ol.View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2
        });

        var map0 = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                  source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            controls: [],
            target: 'map0',
            view: shared_view
        });

        var map1 = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                  source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            controls: [],
            target: 'map1',
            view: shared_view
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Since this solves my particular problem I'll leave it here in case anyone stumbles upon the issue, but since it's not a complete answer to the question, if anyone happens to come up with a solution that doesn't use separate `map` objects I'll accept their answer instead of my own.